# naming class by qt-designer instead of by hand

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, qt-designer

I need to name my class in `qt-designer`,  Unfortunately after each change in `qt-designer` and genertaing `*.ui`  file, i should change `<class> MyClass</class>` by hand.

**My question** is, How change my class name by `qt-designer` , not by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Qt Designer generate ui files with custom names, you need to set the object names for your dialogs/windows/widgets. You can do that in Qt Designers `Property Editor`, after selecting an object.